# Load multiple urls and create one data frame with values

Tags: r, selenium

For one url I can take the value of a variable using this:

```
    library("RSelenium")
    startServer()
    remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
    remDr$open()
    remDr$navigate("http://www.adobe.com/")
    res <- remDr$executeScript('return window.s_adobe.prop1;')
    res2 <- remDr$executeScript('return window.s_adobe.prop13;')
```

If I have more than one urls:

```
http://www.adobe.com/
https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/?promoid=KLXMA
```

How can I take a dataframe in this format:

```
url,prop1,prop13
http://www.adobe.com/,"Home Page Template",""
https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/?promoid=KLXMA,"Full Width Content Page Template",85
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
url_list <- c("http://www.adobe.com/", "https://acrobat.adobe.com/us/en/?promoid=KLXMA")
startServer()
remDr <- remoteDriver(browserName = "chrome")
remDr$open()
df <- data.frame()

for (i in 1:length(url_list)) {
  url <- url_list[i]
  remDr$navigate(url)
  Sys.sleep(15) ##A hacky way that just allows chrome to catch up
  res <- remDr$executeScript('return window.s_adobe.prop1;')
  res2 <- remDr$executeScript('return window.s_adobe.prop13;')
  df <- rbind(df, data.frame(URL = url, prop1 = res[[1]][1], prop2 = res2[[1]][1]))
}
```